# SEO friendly url in PHP htaccess

Tags: php, url, seo, friend

I use Godaddy Apache server to build my own blog, and I did some search of SEO friendly url tutorials, and applied the following code in my web root .htaccess file to transfer links like http://www.bgmemo.com/blog.php?url=2012/08/23/4-steps-to-initialize-Apache-Derby-10-9-1-0-in-Netbeans-7-1-1.html to http://www.bgmemo.com/blog/2012/08/23/4-steps-to-initialize-Apache-Derby-10-9-1-0-in-Netbeans-7-1-1.html :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html$ blog.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html/$ blog.php?url=$1
```

But it does not work. The htaccess is working and other code in it is applied. Who can tell me what is wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you get much better SEO results with content than rewriting urls.

Comment: Just because some people don't realize it... no amount of rewrite rules will change the links in your webpages. You have to update all your existing links. The rewrite rule just tells Apache that the new "pretty" URLs you create, and someone clicks on, should be handled by blog.php.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^blog/([a-zA-Z0-9\-/\.]+)/?$ blog.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I see now that you wanted to use blog in the rewrite... edited the above.

Comment: Hmmm, won't the the regex fail to match something like `blog/something.html` due to the `.` before the html suffix? 
And couldn't we collapse into a single rule by making the trailing slash optional? Perhaps something like `RewriteRule ^blog/([a-zA-Z0-9\-/\.]+)/?$ blog.php?url=$1 [L]`

Comment: Good advice. Updated the above and my own .htaccess with the optional trailing slash. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks ow3n, I tried yesterday， but it is still not working. What else do you think is wrong?

Comment: It looks like there are some PHP errors and the CSS files are not linking: http://www.bgmemo.com/blog/2012/08/21/8-ways-to-speed-up-my-PHP-blog - Try an absolute reference for the CSS and look in your PHP for the error:  

`Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/content/32/9291432/html/blog.php on line 141`


`Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/content/32/9291432/html/blog.php on line 147`

Answer (score 0):

This is the correctly way for don´t have problems with your .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^blog/([a-zA-Z0-9\-/\.]+)/?$ blog.php?url=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```